# How to add a newline/line forward at superuser comments?

Tags: discussion

With pushing [ENTER] button a comment is sent to server.
How does one make a new line inside comments instead?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165268/line-breaks-not-working-in-comments

Comment: Will there be an update, containing new line for comments, for better readability?

Answer (score 11):

You can't.

Comments don't have the same formatting structure as answers. You can make links using [text](url), you can bold &/or italic using asterisks and use `code` backticks, but that's about it.

This links to the entirety of the format spec for comments - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

If you want to play with formatting, there's a sandbox on [Meta Stack Exchange - Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Once I did copy/paste from a formatted text that included a line forward symbol already and that text was 2 lines here also. Why?

Comment: if you can find a functioning example, let's have a look.

Comment: adding 2 spaces (between quotation marks" should work also (from above link)"   "<br><br/>  this is 2nd line"   "<br><br/>3rd line

Comment: The above link quite clearly states it is not possible.... & as you see, that remains true. The only relevant section was the one I linked to the top of the page, highlighted "Comment Formatting", the rest doesn't apply.

Comment: Well, you've tried three times & it hasn't worked yet. What more do you need? [Though I notice you've now removed attempt number three]

Comment: I know i saw 2 short sentences that were flipped to single lines. Maybe there was a special binary character ending on 1st line. Possible? (Tried \0x25 ^M -> no success).

Comment: Actually,
you can paste a multiline text and preserve its newline,
or pressing Shift+Enter to add newline,
but that doesn't matter since the newlines will collapse when posted
(this is a multiline text with newline after commas)
/cc @beyondtime

Comment: @AndrewT. - sure, you can paste what you like, but it will be stripped. That's the whole point.